# camera calibration re-prjection error gives a very high value

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I am a newbie at opencv and camera calibration, to be honest very very newbie .. I am working on camera calibration and UN-distortion project I followed the instructions and the code from  [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html)
and everything works fine for some data-sets but for other there was a problem which is:
I have a dataset with 300 images when I run the project on this dataset I got a re-projection error about 78 "I know that is totally wrong and it should be between 0 and 1" and the undistorted images were a disaster. when I eliminated some Images the re-projection error had become about 0.2 and the undistoted images were fine ..I tracked these images manually and was able to find them. 
the problem is that the images that I excluded were similar to some images which were fine to keep in the data set .. also I am using findchessboardcorners and findchessboardcornersSB and all the corners for the deleted images were detected ..  I read in the opencv tutorial that it is not good to have similar images because that will lead the calibration to fail but my dataset is images from a video so there are many similar images 
I want to know the reason for that.. also I want to know if is it fine to remove the eliminated images from my dataset?

Comment: I forgot to tell you that the pictures are from video and I read in the tutorial:
 Similar images result in similar equations, and similar equations at the calibration step will form an ill-posed problem, so the calibration will fail..so can this be a problem ?